# Thread SIGABRT error in main method, Is it due to simulator or Xcode? or any wrong linking of UI?

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm, simulator

I have doubt about my UI connections, but not sure, I tried giving some links from xib to code but removed some and added (so I have doubt about this, if so, how to cross check all deleted links are cleared? I have cleaned and built many times) . 
Somebody suggested me to use GDB but I cannot find .dmg file of GDB in internet. I will give you more info if required.
    My requirement is when I click on button it should go to "MainViewController" (other xib name).

appdel.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class FirstViewController;

@interface EmyAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property(strong,nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

appdel.m

```
@implementation EmyAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:     (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    FirstViewController *firstViewController =
    [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController"
                                          bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController =
    [[UINavigationController alloc]
     initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

FirstViewctrl.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) MainViewController *mainViewController;
-(IBAction)signIn:(id)sender;
@end
```

FirstViewCtrl.m

```
@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)signIn:(id)sender {

    MainViewController *main = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
}  //Main View Controller is the target for button

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

The error message is:

> [return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
>   NSStringFromClass([EmyAppDelegate class])); //error Thread1: Signal
>   SIGABRT ]

Comment: This error is struggling me from more than 8hrs, what is the problem? i googled about this issue but no solution. I have doubt about my UI connections,but not sure, I tried giving some links from xib to code but removed some and added(so i have doubt about this, if so,how to cross check all deleted links are cleared?i have cleaned and built many times) . Somebody suggested me to use GDB but when i cannot find .dmg file of it. I will give you more info if required.
    My requiremnt is when i click on button it should go to "MainViewController(other xib name)"

Comment: which error it gives?

Comment: In main, at [return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([EmyAppDelegate class])); //error Thread1: Signal SIGABRT ]                           I got diff answers from google, about GDB, about error in code, about UI links etc.

Comment: Resetting and restarting the simulator and XCode didn't clear it up for me, but a reboot did.

Comment: Even i too did that(shutdown and started it), but no use :(

Comment: Enable zombies, enable breakpoints on exceptions and run the app at debug mode, Analyze the project for potential memory management issues: these are the easiest operations you can do with Xcode GUI and no deep knowledge of how they work.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Open up your main.storyboard by right clicking `Open As > Source Code` then search for `connections` the XML will give you a list of every link to any object that you have made from the Storyboard to your ObjC/Swift classes. It should look something like this
    
    `<connections>
          <outlet property="bannerView" destination="3DF-Wy-he3" id="LNt-Qd-cCl"/>
          <outlet property="introScene" destination="SnV-5I-ktF" id="7wY-cV-uAT"/>
          <outlet property="numberOfGamesWonLabel" destination="9P9-nG-aoM" id="bOe-EH-u2y"/>
    </connections>`

If there are any there that no longer exist ie a variable deleted in the ObjC/Swift class then remove the entire line. For introScene you would delete 
    
    `<outlet property="introScene" destination="SnV-5I-ktF" id="7wY-cV-uAT"/>`